# Binding issues with GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am totally confused with the way ASP.NET `GridView` binding works.

I have a `GridView`. Now, on the page load (using `!IsPostBack`) I am binding the `GridView`.

My gridview has an edit button. When I click on it, the `GridView` becomes blank. Behaviour could be expected, because when I click on the edit button, a postback happens and, because I have binded the `GridView` inside the `!IsPostback` condition, it won't bind the `GridView`.

Now, if I remove the `GridView` binding, and place it outside the `!IsPostback` condition, the edit button works. But, I am unable to get the edited value from the `TextBox`. In this case, too, the behaviour could be expected, as when the update button is clicked, the `GridView` is re-binded, because the binding this time has been done outside the `!IsPostback` condition.

So, I want to know what could be the proper code for the edit button to work, and at the same time, the edited values from the `TextBox` could be retrieved.

Question Updated with Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdExternalLinkSection1" ShowFooter="true" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="5" EnableViewState="true">
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    External Link Title
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtExternalLinkTitleEmptySection1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    External Link Url
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtExternalLinkUrlEmptySection1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnExternalLinkEmptySection1" OnCommand="grdExternalLinkSection_Button_Clicks" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="headernew,1" style="padding:3px; width:56px;" />
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblExternalLinkTitleSection1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Title") %></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExternalLinkTitleEditSection1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExternalLinkTitleFooterSection1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Url">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblExternalLinkUrlSection1" runat="server"><%# Eval("Url")%></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExternalLinkUrlEditSection1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Url") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtExternalLinkUrlFooterSection1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manage">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnExternalLinkEditSection1" OnCommand="grdExternalLinkSection_Button_Clicks" runat="server" CommandName="Editing,1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' Text="Edit" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnExternalLinkDeleteSection1" OnCommand="grdExternalLinkSection_Button_Clicks" runat="server" CommandName="Deleting,1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' Text="Delete" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnExternalLinkUpdateSection1" OnCommand="grdExternalLinkSection_Button_Clicks" runat="server" CommandName="Updating,1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' Text="Update" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnExternalLinkCancelSection1" OnCommand="grdExternalLinkSection_Button_Clicks" runat="server" CommandName="Canceling,1" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' Text="Cancel" />
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnExternalLinkAddFooterSection1" OnCommand="grdExternalLinkSection_Button_Clicks" runat="server" CommandName="Footer,1" Text="Add" />
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

below is the function which does the binding work:

```
 GridView grid;
    protected void BindExternalLinks(int SectionID, string ControlName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("user_Newsletter_GetExternalLinks", connection))
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@SectionID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = SectionID;
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PortalID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PortalID;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                grid = (GridView)this.FindControl(ControlName);
                grid.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void BindAllExternalLinks()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= NewsLetterSectionCount; i++)
        {
            BindExternalLinks(i, "grdExternalLinkSection" + i);
            grid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

below is my PageLoad:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindAllExternalLinks();
        }
    }
```

and below is my command buttons event: i have kept the handler common for all command buttons:

```
   protected void grdExternalLinkSection_Button_Clicks(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = (e.CommandArgument != "") ? Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) : -1;
        string[] commandNames = e.CommandName.ToString().Split(',');
        string command = commandNames[0].ToString().ToLower();
        int sectionID = Convert.ToInt32(commandNames[1]);
        GridView grid = (GridView)this.FindControl("grdExternalLinkSection" + sectionID);
        try
        {
            if (command == "headernew")
            {
                TextBox title = grid.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtExternalLinkTitleEmptySection" + sectionID) as TextBox;
                TextBox url = grid.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("txtExternalLinkUrlEmptySection" + sectionID) as TextBox;
                UpdateExternalLinks(ModifyExternalLinks.Insert, sectionID, title.Text, url.Text);
                MessageShow("External Link Added Successfully");
            }
            else if (command == "editing")
            {
                //grid.EditIndex = rowIndex;
            }
            else if (command == "canceling")
            {
                grid.EditIndex = -1;
            }
            else if (command == "footer")
            {
                Response.Write("Inside Footer");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
        BindExternalLinks(sectionID, "grdExternalLinkSection" + sectionID);
        grid.DataBind(); //here i am binding once the records are modified.
    }
```

Comment: Please split your posts into paragraphs, so that they are not so difficult to read.  Also, when possible, try to use correct capitalization and punctuation.

Comment: Show us your GridView aspx markup. What means _blank_ and is ViewState enabled?

Comment: You haven't shown the whole GridView, i'm missing the button with CommandName="editing". And wherefrom `BindExternalLinks` is called?

Comment: i updated the Whole `GridView` and the `BindExternalLinks` function i have already pasted, check above `BindAllExternalLinks` function, hope that would help you to help me

Comment: You should use the debugger to see what happens. Sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: actually this code is running on my local server and not on the local machine, can you tell me how can i run the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. `BindAllExternalLinks()` should be inside the `if (!IsPostback)` block, correct.

The additional thing you should do is to rebind the grid after you have done your editing:

```
else if (command == "editing")
{
    // do your update stuff here

    BindAllExternalLinks();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rebind the gridview under each postback event(). Even if you bind it to an object datasource or SQL DataSource, you have to call the databind method after every postback request like

```
              MyGridview.DataBind();
              UpdatePanel1.Update();
```